# fire intent from the service class for power button

Tags: android

I want to open my application with the press of power button twice.

My application don't show any problem if I show a toast on the service class but when I fire intent to the other class is show problem : `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:calling startActivity()` from outside of an Activity context requires the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You are starting Activity from outer class so add this to yout intent **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

Comment: sir it work well from the application but when i close my application and hit the power button twice it show following error  E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50000010 } in com.example.safeme.broad@416ecca0
 E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773)